# custom dropdown css horizontal

Tags: css

I want a custom `CSS` dropdown in horizontal.

I have tried but, coding is not giving me result as expected.. Have a look at the image :

[image]

```js
if(!$dropdown.length) {
                        var dropdownMarkup = '<li class="dropdown responsivetabs-more ">'
                        + '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">. . .</a>'
                        + '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right ">'
                        + '</ul>';
                        $dropdown = $(dropdownMarkup);
                        $element.append($dropdown);

                    }
```

```css
.nav-tabs li { position: relative; float: left; margin: 0 5px -1px 0; padding: 0; }
.nav-tabs li a { display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 0px #cccccc solid;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 165px;
z-index: 1000;
text-align: right;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: please explain your problem clearly

Comment: sorry for my bad language, my problem is like picture (marked red) i want, horizontal dropdown it does not exceed the line. thank you

Comment: not enough info. create a jsfiddle, including html.

Comment: I edited some W3C code to add more style and options, this works well, fully customizable and minimal code with animation options. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G0D0M6V0KW5X